# cursor to pointer on image in e-mail newsletter

Tags: image, email, newsletter, mouse-cursor

When I make a newsletter with a linked image in it, the css style cursor:pointer; doesn't work on the image. Any ideas how to solve this? I think when people see the 'hand-cursor' they're more likely to click it.

```
<tbody>
<table width="100%">
    <tr align="center">
        <td colspan="2"><a id="poster" style="cursor:pointer;cursor:hand;" href="http://www.example.com/"><img width="600" border="0" src="http://www.example.com/newsletter/images/0917-newsletter.jpg"></a></td>
    </tr>   
</table>
</tbody>
```

Just to be extra clear. The cursor works in the browser, but after copying and pasting in an e-mail, the received newsletter doesn't show the cursor.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Tip: If I see HTML in an email I'm less likely to click it.

Comment: Thnx Flexo, but the newsletter is received only after subscription on the website. The subscribers will expect images, because of the purpose of the newsletter. The only thing missing is the little hand to notify them the images are also links...

Comment: Then I would wonder why you had subscribed in the first place... Why would you subscribe to something you actually don't wanna receive?

Comment: Too bad you removed your post, I thought we had a nice little discussion going...

Comment: I was going to say that when I subscribe to any list I expect it to be plain text or at worst multipart, but was getting rather offtopic.